# Ajuda com instalação de Ionic Cordova via Terminal - Mac!

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, ionic2, terminal, npm

Estou tentando realizar a instalação do Ionic para desenvolver um app mobile e estou seguindo um passo-a-passo do site:[Tableless](https://tableless.com.br/tutorial-ionic-meu-primeiro-app/), porém na parte em que é pedido para realizar o comando `npm install -g ionic cordova`, os pacotes começam a ser instalados, entretanto quando a instalação é finalizada ele me retorna isso via o próprio terminal:

> MacBook-Pro-de-Lucas:~ lucas$ npm install -g ionic cordova npm WARN
> deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead /usr/local/lib └──
> ionic@3.4.0
>
> npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
>
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
> "-g" "ionic" "cordova"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.11.0
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>
> npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
>
> npm ERR! code EACCES
>
> npm ERR! errno -13
>
> npm ERR! syscall symlink
>
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink
> '../lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova' -> '/usr/local/bin/cordova'
>
> npm ERR!     at Error (native)
>
> npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink
> '../lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova' -> '/usr/local/bin/cordova'
>
> npm ERR!     at Error (native)
>
> npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>
> npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
>
> npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova',
>
> npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/cordova' }
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/lucas/npm-debug.log
>
> MacBook-Pro-de-Lucas:~ lucas$ ionic --version
> -bash: ionic: command not found

Preciso de uma força Galera... :/

Comment: Esse tutorial do tableless é muito antigo, ainda está usando Ionic 1. Utilizando npm install -g ionic cordova vc irá instalar a versão atual. Recomendo seguir o tutorial do próprio site do Ionic https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/ . Lembre-se de instalar também o Node.js 6 ou superior

Comment: Tente executar o comando como super usuário através do comando sudo su.